# jQuery function to check if an email address exists

Tags: php, jquery

I have a very limited jQuery experience and I was wondering if you can help me with a function that has to check, with an AJAX request, if an email address exists or not.

Until now I have this piece of code for email checking:

```
$('input#email').bind('blur', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/email.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'email=' + $('input#email').val(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            if (html == 1) alert('Email exists!');
        }
    });
});
```

How can I make a function out of this and use it like this:

```
if (!email_exists($('input#email').val())) {
    $('#error_email').text('Email exists').show();
    return false;
}
```

My PHP code looks like this:

```
$email = ($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];

$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` \n"."WHERE `users`.`email` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo '0';
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want this kind of call to be asynchronous (the A in AJAX). This means you don't want to tie up the application waiting for a call to return. Using an `email_exists` function and waiting for it to return is not *event driven programming*. Create a function called `check_email_exists` and have that function perform the `.show()` or just have the `blur` handle it.

Comment: @webbiedave: I tried with the blur and placed the checking outside the $('#form').submit(function(e){}); and it works fine, but if you submit the form the error disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really must have an answer returned from the function synchronously, you can use a synchronous XMLHttpRequest instead of the normal asynchronous one (the ‘A’ in AJAX):

```
function email_exists(email) {
    var result= null;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/email.php',
        data: {email: email},
        cache: false,
        async: false, // boo!
        success: function(data) {
            result= data;
        }
    });
    return result=='1';
}
```

However this is *strongly discouraged* as it will make the browser hang up whilst it is waiting for the answer, which is quite user-unfriendly.

(nb: also, pass an object to `data` to let jQuery cope with the formatting for you. Otherwise, you would need to do `'email='+encodeURIComponent(email)` explicitly.)

You can't have a function that synchronously returns a value from an asynchronous action, or vice versa (you would need threads or co-routines to do that, and JavaScript has neither). Instead, embrace asynchronous programming and have the result returned to a passed-in callback:

```
$('#email').bind('change', function() {
    check_email($('#email').val(), function(exists) {
        if (exists)
            $('#error_email').text('Email exists').show();
    });
});

function check_email(email, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/email.php',
        data: {email: email},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data=='1');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already made it a "function" by attaching it to the blur event of your input. I would just

```
success: function(html) {
  if (html == 1) 
    $('#error_email').text('Email exists').show();
  else
    $('#error_email').hide();
}
```

Comment: I know, but I want to make it a different function.